# Call js generated from typescript in blazor using IJSObjectReference

Tags: c#, typescript, blazor, blazor-server-side

Hi I have a question about using Blazor and typescript.

My typescript:

```
namespace JSInteropWithTypeScript {

    export class Generator {
        public showAlert(): void {
            alert("INTEROP");
        }
    }

    export function Load(): void {
        window['generator'] = new Generator();
    }
}

JSInteropWithTypeScript.Load();
```

And here is generated JS:

```
var JSInteropWithTypeScript;
(function (JSInteropWithTypeScript) {
    var Generator = /** @class */ (function () {
        function Generator() {
        }
        Generator.prototype.showAlert = function () {
            alert("INTEROP");
        };
        return Generator;
    }());
    JSInteropWithTypeScript.Generator = Generator;
    function Load() {
        window['generator'] = new Generator();
    }
    JSInteropWithTypeScript.Load = Load;
})(JSInteropWithTypeScript || (JSInteropWithTypeScript = {}));
JSInteropWithTypeScript.Load();
//# sourceMappingURL=generator.js.map
```

Next I want to call compiled js script so I have a simple component with button:

```
@namespace Components.Reports.Components.Generator
@inherits ControlsBase

<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="ShowAlert"> BUTON </button>
```

In base class for this component I want to lazy load (so i do not need to add every script in _Host just use them when they are needed) this script file and call this function, so I made this contraption:

```
public class ControlsBase : ComponentBase, IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask;

    [Inject]
    protected IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; set; }
    
    public ControlsBase()
    {
        Task<IJSObjectReference> jsInvokes() => this.JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./_content/Components/js/generator.js").AsTask();
        this. moduleTask = new Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>>(jsInvokes);
    }

    public async Task ShowAlert()
    {
        try
        {
            var module = await moduleTask.Value;
            await module.InvokeVoidAsync("showAlert");
        }
        catch (JSException jsException)
        {
            logger.Error($"Problem with js interop {jsException}");
        }
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (moduleTask.IsValueCreated)
        {
            var module = await moduleTask.Value;
            await module.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

So now I want to call this, my problem/question is when I call compiled js script I am getting

> Could not find 'showAlert' ('showAlert' was undefined).

When i use vanilla code like:

```
export function showAlert() {
  alert("INTEROP");
}
```

it works.

So what am I doing wrong with typescript?

**EDIT**

Using @Haytam guide I remade my ts to simple:

```
namespace JSInteropWithTypeScript {
    export class Generator {
        public ShowAlert(): void {
            alert("INTEROP");
        }
    }
}

function showAlert(): void {
    let generator = new JSInteropWithTypeScript.Generator();
    generator.ShowAlert();
}
```

And it compiles to js:

```
var JSInteropWithTypeScript;
(function (JSInteropWithTypeScript) {
    var Generator = /** @class */ (function () {
        function Generator() {
        }
        Generator.prototype.ShowAlert = function () {
            alert("INTEROP");
        };
        return Generator;
    }());
    JSInteropWithTypeScript.Generator = Generator;
})(JSInteropWithTypeScript || (JSInteropWithTypeScript = {}));
function showAlert() {
    var generator = new JSInteropWithTypeScript.Generator();
    generator.ShowAlert();
}
```

But to work properly I need to manually add export before function in js.I know that the cause for this error is that TypeScript, by default, produces JavaScript code that is designed for use through various package managers that cater to the exports and modules. Such tools are usully Node.js or WebPack. I can turn it off by using tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "none"
   }
}
```

But still js interop works only when function is marked as export in js. Any ideas how to handle that?

**EDIT2:**

I think problem lays in lazy loding, added generated js script as static resource:

```
 <script src="_content/Components/js/generator.js"></script>
```

and used code:

```
    public async Task OnClick()
    {
        try
        {
            await this.JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("showAlert");
        }
        catch (JSException jsException)
        {
            logger.Error($"Problem with js interop {jsException}");
        }
    }
```

In my component base and it is alive, but still just for curiosity I want to make n this lazy loading. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the generated JS from the TS?

Comment: Sure thing, just added

Comment: September 2021 and this issue persists. For anyone searching for a fix to this, there's none - at least for now. You have to specify the js-file in a script tag in`_Host.cshtml`.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems here:

1. Blazor JS Isolation works with [JavaScript Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). Putting functions in `window` is not required anymore, that's why they added this isolation in the first place.
2. Since Blazor JS Isolation works with JS modules, it expects exported functions directly. I believe no matter what you try, the generated JS from using TS classes will not work.

I think you should try to export the functions directly.

**EDIT**

Based on your latest edit, doesn't this work?

```
export function showAlert(): void {
    let generator = new JSInteropWithTypeScript.Generator();
    generator.ShowAlert();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I removed that load statement and moved function show alert outside class and namespace, but i need to manually add export in compiled js without it blazor does not see that function and when I add it in TS I am getting exports is not defined exception. I will update my question for more details.

Comment: @WojciechSzabowicz Made an edit to my answer, I believe you can use the `export` keyword in TS too no?

Comment: Not in my case (but I am not using npm as I wrote all info i found are telling to turnoff exports or to init npm) when i add export before function in ts, in js export looks like: exports.showAlert = showAlert; and calling it throws an exception.

Comment: @WojciechSzabowicz Did you ever manage to resolve the exports exception? I've just come across this myself.

Comment: @Andrew, oh forgot about this question. If I remember correctly in _Host.cshtml I've changed <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" /> to <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />