# Is it Possible to Import an Exported JavaScript Module Class as Interop Class in Blazor?

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

When creating a Razor Class Library in the latest Visual Studio 2019 for my Blazor server-side solution, I see the following files:

`ExampleJsInterop.cs`

```
    public class ExampleJsInterop : IAsyncDisposable
    {
        private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask;

        public ExampleJsInterop(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
        {
            moduleTask = new(() => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
               "import", "./_content/MyNamespace/exampleJsInterop.js").AsTask());
        }

        public async ValueTask<string> Prompt(string message)
        {
            var module = await moduleTask.Value;
            return await module.InvokeAsync<string>("showPrompt", message);
        }

        public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {
            if (moduleTask.IsValueCreated)
            {
                var module = await moduleTask.Value;
                await module.DisposeAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

`exampleJsInterop.js`

```
// This is a JavaScript module that is loaded on demand. It can export any number of
// functions, and may import other JavaScript modules if required.

export function showPrompt(message) {
  return prompt(message, 'Type anything here');
}
```

This is very interesting.  However, what I would like to do is [use classes instead](https://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial/classes/).  I do not see any reference to this in any links that I have searched, and the closest StackOverflow question I have found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908748/call-js-generated-from-typescript-in-blazor-using-ijsobjectreference).

Is it possible to export classes in JavaScript/browser and then import them into Blazor via interop?  If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I do is use a TypeScript class like this (pseudo-code) in a folder outside wwwroot with tsconfig set to compile to wwwroot in the Class Library:

```
class SizeHelpers {
    public GetBoundingClientRect(element: HTMLElement): DOMRect {
        return element.getBoundingClientRect();
    }
}
```

Then use this to export it (in the same file):

```
export function getSizeHelpers(): SizeHelpers {
    return new SizeHelpers();
}
```

Then in C# I import this file on demand like this in a Service:

```
    var helpersInstance = await helpersModule.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("getSizeHelpers");
    Helpers = new Helpers(helpersInstance);
```

Then in C# I do this to consume the function:

```
 public class SizeHelpers
    {
        private readonly IJSObjectReference _instance;

        public SizeHelpers(IJSObjectReference instance)
        {
            _instance = instance;
        }

        public ValueTask<BoundingClientRectangle> GetBoundingClientRect(ElementReference element)
        {
            return _instance.InvokeAsync<BoundingClientRectangle>("GetBoundingClientRect", element);
        }
}
```

Comment: What is "helpersModule" in the third code snippet? for what concerns "Helpers" instead I suppose it is the same thing as "SizeHelpers" in the fourth code snippet?